# Laravel Lumen + Broadcasting + Redis + Class pusher not found

Tags: laravel, lumen

So I'm trying to setup broadcasting using redis however I can't get this to work as I'm missing some configuration options I guess.

.env file

```
...
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
...
```

Controller

```
event(new TestEvent());
```

TestEvent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events\Socket;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{

    protected $data;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = [
            'payload' => [
                'test' => 'test'
            ],
            'message' => 'another'
        ];
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {

        return new PrivateChannel('user.2');
    }
}
```

However, when I run this in my failed_jobs table in the database this error pops up:

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'Pusher' not found in /var/www/vendor/illuminate/broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php:216
Stack trace:

## 0 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php(193): Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastManager->createPusherDriver(Array)

## 1 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php(164): Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastManager->resolve('pusher')

## 2 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php(153): Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastManager->get('pusher')

## 3 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php(140): Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastManager->driver('pusher')

## 4 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/broadcasting/BroadcastServiceProvider.php(30): Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastManager->connection()

## 5 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(726): Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider->Illuminate\Broadcasting{closure}(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array)

## 6 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))

## 7 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Illuminate\Cont...')

## 8 /var/www/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(210): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\Cont...')

## 9 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(156): Laravel\Lumen\Application->make('Illuminate\Cont...')

## 10 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(116): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::addDependencyForCallParameter(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Object(ReflectionParameter), Array, Array)

## 11 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::getMethodDependencies(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array)

## 12 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}()

## 13 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Object(Closure))

## 14 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array, NULL)

## 15 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)

## 16 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(114): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))

## 17 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))

## 18 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))

## 19 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(42): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent), false)

## 20 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/queue/Jobs/Job.php(69): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Array)

## 21 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/queue/Worker.php(317): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()

## 22 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/queue/Worker.php(267): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))

## 23 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/queue/Worker.php(113): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))

## 24 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))

## 25 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(85): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')

## 26 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()

## 27 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)

## 28 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}()

## 29 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Object(Closure))

## 30 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array, NULL)

## 31 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/console/Command.php(182): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)

## 32 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(262): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))

## 33 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/console/Command.php(167): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))

## 34 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(888): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

## 35 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(224): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

## 36 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(125): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

## 37 /var/www/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Console/Kernel.php(84): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

## 38 /var/www/artisan(35): Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

## 39 {main}

This is strange because it shouldn't event be trying to create the Pusher instance.

I've tried with composer dump-autoload, composer clear-cache, php artisan clear-compiled...

It is funny because if I try this code and dump the instance I get a good configured BroadcastManager:

```
$broadcastManager = (new BroadcastManager(app()))->connection();
```

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Do not tell what happened after your message, try it

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server --no-scripts
```

or

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

or

edit line in **"vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php"**

> "use Pusher;" to "use Pusher\Pusher;"

or

**in your config/app.php add this line to aliases**

> 'Pusher' => Pusher\Pusher::class,

Comment: In `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` I have `'Pusher\\Pusher' => $vendorDir . '/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php',` So, the `use  Pusher\Pusher` is correct. Why would I need to add an alias?